# Real-time plotting using Android plot from bluetooth data

Tags: bluetooth, real-time

I have modified the OrientationSensorExample from androidplot website and currently able to plot some dummy waves sourced from my `/res` folder.

I would like to now implement Bluetooth function for my application but I do not know where or how to start, please give me some advise. Thank you to all who reads this thread.

Answer (score 1):

For communicating with Bluetooth devices, I would recommend you to read the Bluetooth Dev Guide firstly 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html

Then play with the Bluetooth Chat sample.
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html

For real time plotting, I am currently struggling with this problem. Once you can communicate via bluetooth, what you need to do is draw the graph dynamically (real time), I don't know if androidplot support that.

Please let me know if you have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on a solution to do this as well. Communication is based on the Bluetooth Chat sample. It works great with my Arduino Uno and a Bluetooth Mate module. I will do the plotting with the AndroidPlot libraries.

You can get a copy of my code at:

https://bitbucket.org/SmallJoeMan/serial-log/

https://bitbucket.org/SmallJoeMan/serial-plot/

The serial-plot is not fully functional just yet. I'm currently writing the code to make the plot dynamic although progress is slow as the AndroidPlot website is currently down gah!